# Android 4.0.4 bluetooth dongle pairing

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, bluetooth-pairing

I have a problem with an Android device when it pairs with a Bluetooth dongle. This device (Honda Connect) shows up a dialog asking to put a certain pin on the bluetooth dongle to pair (0000) ... unfortunately this dongle has a different pin and it's not possibile to 'change' such pin (AFAIK). Is there a way to change the default pin from 0000 to a different one?

Answer (score 0):

In the specific case of using Honda Connect (Android device) this problem can be fixed trough Honda Connect WiFi / Bluetooth settings. This form (NOT Android Bluetooth settings) allows to change the pairing code. After this maneouvre (and a soft reset if required) the bluetooth pairing will be completed succesfully without pairing code request.